# Casperjs: can't find variable '$' while jQuery is injected

Tags: jquery, casperjs

I inject jquery with

```
casper.options.clientScripts = ["jquery-latest.min.js"];
```

But later I get that

```
[debug] [phantom] Automatically injected jquery-latest.min.js client side
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

On line

```
var $j_object = $(".market_listing");
```

This question has been answered for casperjs testing, but I didn't find a way to apply these solutions to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

try changing to this line:

```
casper.options.clientScripts.push("jquery-latest.min.js");
```

another way is this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: [
      'includes/jquery-latest.min.js',// These two scripts will be injected in remote
      'includes/underscore.js'   // DOM on every request
    ],
   ...
});
```

[See the documentation about `require('casper').create()`.](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#index-1)

Comment: I did it the second way at first and it didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the evaluate function when you are ready to use jQuery in addition to loading the script as mentioned previously.

```
casper.evaluate(function(){ 
  /// Page including jQuery is loaded
});
```